# How to lag dates in form of strings in R

Tags: r, date, lag

The following vector of Dates is given in form of a string sequence:

```
d <- c("01/09/1991","01/10/1991","01/11/1991","01/12/1991")
```

I would like to exemplary **lag this vector by 1 month**, that means to produce the following structure:

```
d <- c("01/08/1991","01/09/1991","01/10/1991","01/11/1991")
```

My data is much larger and I must impose higher lags as well, but this seems to be the basis I need to know.
By doing this, I would like to have the same format in the end again:`("%d/%m/%Y)`. How can this be done in R? I found a couple of packages (e.g. `lubridate`), but I always have to convert between formats (strings, dates and more) so it's a bit messy and seems prone to mistake.
edit: some more info on why I want to do this: I am using this vector as rownames of a matrix, so I would prefer a solution where the final outcome is a string vector again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not use any packages.  We convert to `"POSIXlt"` class, subtract one from the month component and convert back:

```
fmt <- "%d/%m/%Y"
lt <- as.POSIXlt(d, format = fmt)
lt$mon <- lt$mon - 1
format(lt, format = fmt)
## [1] "01/08/1991" "01/09/1991" "01/10/1991" "01/11/1991"
```

Comment: Interesting I didn't know this could be done with `POSIXlt`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

My solution uses `lubridate`but it does return what you want in the specified format:

```
require(lubridate)
d <- c("01/09/1991","01/10/1991","01/11/1991","01/12/1991")  
format(as.Date(d,format="%d/%m/%Y")-months(1),'%d/%m/%Y')

[1] "01/08/1991" "01/09/1991" "01/10/1991" "01/11/1991"
```

You can then change the lag and (if you want) the output (which is this part : `'%d/%m/%Y'`) by specifying what you want.